# converting Informatica transformations to Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark-sql, informatica, pyspark

I am trying  to convert informatica transformation to pyspark transformation, but I am stuck in replacing char in the code shown below:

```
"DECODE(TRUE,
ISNULL(v_check_neg_**) OR v_check_neg_** = '', 
i_default,
NOT IS_NUMBER(v_check_neg_** , 
i_default,
REPLACECHR(0,v_check_neg_**, '+-0123456789.' ,'')<>'', 
i_default,
TO_DECIMAL(v_check_neg_**,5))


v_check_neg_** = IIF(INSTR(i_string_**,'-')!=0,'-'||SUBSTR(i_string_**,1,INSTR(i_string_**,'-')-1),i_string_**)"
```

This is what I tried:

```
def is_digit(value):
    if value:
        return value.isdigit()
    else:
        return False

is_digit_udf = udf(is_digit, BooleanType())

df_informatica=df_informatica.withColumn(column_name,when((isnull(col(column_name)) |(col(column_name==' ')),i_default).when(is_digit_udf(col(column_name)),i_default)

df_informatica=df_informatica.withColumn
```

Please help me convert informatica to pyspark transformation.

Comment: i dont have datframe for this ,this assignment for pre production

Comment: can you edit your question and  describe what input informatica function takes and what does it output?

Comment: v_check_neg_** = IIF(INSTR(i_string_**,'-')!=0,'-'||SUBSTR(i_string_**,1,INSTR(i_string_**,'-')-1),i_string_**)"   it would be great if you help me to convert this particular command into pyspark   i_string is column name

Comment: I have no idea what does this function means in Informatica and what input it takes and what it produces. may be someone who knows spark and informatica both can answer this. if you can help us with some sample data then would be easy to answer this..

Comment: for example. you can just explain your informatica function with a sample input and a expected results. that will work

Comment: even i dont know informatica , I am also suffering for that only

Comment: Great. well in that case. you should at least know what going as an Input and what you are expecting as an Output.  This is the minimum requirement.

Answer (score 0):

i cant see whole statement but your decode logic is - 
if (v_check_neg_** is null or v_check_neg_**='' or v_check_neg_** is not number or v_check_neg_** has anything other than numbers) then i_default 
else TO_DECIMAL(v_check_neg_**,5)

Use python to check above cases and you should be good to go.
Like you can use string.isnumeric() to check positive number. And use try except to check -ve, decimal etc.
Example to check negative number-

```
def check_negative(s):
    try:
        f = float(s)
        if (f < 0):
            return True
        # Otherwise return false
        return False
    except ValueError:
        return False
```